# Is there a site with video-based language courses?

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, online-learning

I would like to know a site like [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) but with language courses.

Are there any sites like that?

Comment: YouTube, though broad, should contain tons of language learning videos

Comment: @PythonMaster I know, Anyway I would like a site just for language courses.

Comment: When you say "a site like Udemy", does that mean you are interested only in [MOOC platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course), or in online learning in general?

Comment: I mean a site to learn with video courses.

Comment: There are many such sites. What searching have you attempted? How did you come up short?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try [Yabla](https://www.yabla.com/), [FluentU](http://www.fluentu.com/) (which I like because of its native pronunciation videos), or [Omniglot](http://omniglot.com/language/videos/index.htm) (which is comprehensive but has only a few languages).